# Почему в программировании число 01/02/03.. больше 0?

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно было выполнить проверку, является ли переменная числом большим нулю, в php and javascript. Решил без всяких функций, isnan и так далее, выполнить это так - if(var > 0), но столкнулся с тем что если var равняется к примеру 02, то проверка возвращает true. Как быть?

Comment: Потому что integer значения с первым нулем преобразуются в целые числа `var_dump(02)` будет равно `int(2)`

Comment: Если у вас откуда-то берутся подобные значения с первым нулем, то они явно передаются как string. Следовательно проверяем строку на наличии первого нуля `$value = '02'; if ($value[0] === '0') { $value = 0; }` и возвращаем значение как ноль.

Comment: Какому числу с вашей точки зрения эквивалентно "01" чтобы оно было не >0?